# 'The parameters dictionary contains a null entry' error, Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

On my Web API I have a Document Controller with two simple actions:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class DocumentController : ApiController
{    
    public String Get(int id)
    {
        return "test";
    }

    public String Get(string name)
    {
        return "test2";
    }
}
```

The following URL (executes the first function) works fine:

> http://localhost:1895/API/Document/5

But this URL (should execute the second function):

> http://localhost:1895/API/Document/test

Throws this error:

> {
>     "message": "The request is invalid.",
>   "messageDetail": "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'xx.yy.Document Get(Int32)' in 'API.Controllers.DocumentController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."
>   }

This is the `MapHttpRoute` in the WebApiConfig:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

What am I doing wrong? Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second function has a parameter `name`, and the default parameter is called `id`.  With your current setup, you can access the second function on

> http://localhost:1895/API/Document/?name=test

To make the URLs work as you have specified previously, I would suggest using [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) and [route constraints](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints).

Enable attribute routing:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Define routes on your methods:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Document")]
public class DocumentController : ApiController
{    
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public String GetById(int id)   // The name of this function can be anything now
    {
        return "test";
    }

    [Route("{name}"]
    [HttpGet]
    public String GetByName(string name)
    {
        return "test2";
    }
}
```

In this example, `GetById` has a constraint on the route (`{id:int}`) which specifies that the parameter must be an integer.  `GetByName` has no such constraint so should match when the parameter is NOT an integer.

Comment: Thank you, could you just explain me why I also need to include the `[RoutePrefix("api/Document")]`?

Comment: That defines the base route for the controller.  You could leave it out, but you'd need to change to `[Route("api/Document/{id:int}")]` - your choice.

Comment: Working perfectly, Thank you very much for the clear answer!